# Maximum depth of a theoretical function stack due to a recursive function?

Tags: recursion, data-structures, stack

If we have a theoretical stack memory that never gets full and we have a simple recursive function

```
recurse(n):
    if n > 0:
        recurse(n-1)
        recurse(n-2)
    return
```

Is it reasonable to argue that the theoretical stack has at most *n* stack frames at any point in the execution of `recurse(n)` since it is impossible for `recurse(k)` to be on top of `recurse(i)` if 0 <= k < i <= n, since this implies that `recurse(i)` called `recurse(k)` (which is impossible based on the function body). If my reasoning is correct, then the maximum depth must be the case when the function stack looks like the following:

`(BOTTOM-MOST)|recursion(n)|recursion(n-1)|...|recursion(2)|recursion(1) (TOP-MOST)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to prove. Map it out for yourself -

```
recurse(0)
```

```
recurse(1)
  recurse(0)
  recurse(-1)
```

```
recurse(2)
  recurse(1)
    recurse(0)
    recurse(-1)
  recurse(0)
```

```
recurse(3)
  recurse(2)
    recurse(1)
      recurse(0)
      recurse(-1)
    recurse(0)
  recurse(1)
    recurse(0)
    recurse(-1)
```

```
recurse(4)
  recurse(3)
    recurse(2)
      recurse(1)
        recurse(0)
        recurse(-1)
      recurse(0)
    recurse(1)
      recurse(0)
      recurse(-1)
  recurse(2)
    recurse(1)
      recurse(0)
      recurse(-1)
    recurse(0)
```

This is why `fib(n)` for large `n` will not overflow the stack, and instead tie up your CPU for a long time. For small `n` such as `n = 20`, the result is computed in 1,048,576 steps, but only uses 20 frames -

```js
function fib(x)
{ if (x < 2n)
    return x
  else
    return fib(x - 1n) + fib(x - 2n)
}

console.log("result %s", fib(20n))
// result 6765
```

For larger `n` like `n = 200`, it would take a staggering  1,606,938,044,258,990,275,541,962,092,341,162,602,522,202,993,782,792,835,301,376 computations, but with only a stack depth of 200, would not cause an overflow. However even at 1,000,000,000 computations per second, it would take 50,955,671,114,250,072,156,962,268,275,658,377,807,020,642 **years** to complete -

```js
function fib(x)
{ if (x < 2n)
    return x
  else
    return fib(x - 1n) + fib(x - 2n)
}

console.log("result %s", fib(200n))
// result ...
```

If you tried to run `fib(200)` above, JavaScript will cause you browser to hang until long after the sun dies. Refresh this tab and we can compute the answer in just **1 millisecond**. This rewrite of `fib` uses linear recursion, computing `n = 200` will only take 200 steps and 200 frames -

```js
function fib(x, a = 0n, b = 1n)
{ if (x == 0n)
    return a
  else
    return fib(x - 1n, b, a + b)
}

console.time("fib(200)")
console.log("result %s", fib(200n))
console.timeEnd("fib(200)")
// result 280571172992510140037611932413038677189525
// fib(200): 1.000ms
```

If you use a `while` loop, it can be done in 200 steps and just 1 frame. But that's not recursion, so maybe it's not worth talking about in this post.

Answer (score 1):

When `n = 0` there is one stack frame for the function call itself - you can't have less than one stack frame for any `n` - so the formula for the maximum number of stack frames is `max(1, n+1)`, not `n` exactly. Otherwise your reasoning is correct, and this formula can be proved by induction:

- In the base case when `n <= 0`, there is one stack frame, which is equal to `max(1, n+1)` because `n+1 <= 1`.
- Otherwise when `n >= 1`, two recursive calls are made, one with a stack depth of `max(1, n)` and the other with a stack depth of `max(1, n-1)` by the inductive hypothesis. So the maximum stack depth including the current stack frame for the call on `n` equals `1 + max(max(1, n), max(1, n-1))`. This can be simplified to `1+n` because `n` is the largest of the `max` operands, and `1+n` does equal `max(1, n+1)` as required.